# How to append highcharts on same div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a code to plot a highcharts on my website, I need to plot multiple charts on same div`(container)`, so please guide to reach this, below is my code

```
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
       chart: {
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 10,
            height:150
        },
```

I tried this for append `$('#container').append.highcharts('StockChart',` but it seems like a wrong syntex,please share your answer,thanks

Comment: solution seems pretty obvious, add more child elements in container to insert charts into

Comment: why would you want all the charts on the same div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the following process for each child chart you need.

```
var chartDiv = document.createElement('div'); // Create a new div
$('#container').append(chartDiv); // Append it to your container
$(chartDiv).highcharts(.....); // Initialize highcharts in that div
```

Comment: Surely you can at least try that part out? Replace the "`.....`" in my code with what you pass in your highcharts function call. `'StockChart', {
       chart: {
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 10,
            height:150
        }`

Answer (score 3):

Taken directly from highcharts documentation pages:

> [To combine several chart types in one chart you only need to create series of different types](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types):

```
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
}, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'John',
    data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
}, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
}, {
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Average',
    data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33]
}]
```

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/).

Comment: it show all in one chart, but i need in different charts

Comment: @AshokSri Ahh got it. See my other answer. Left this one here because future readers finding this question may be looking for that kind of information.